# Seeing two Omniture custom link types in Omnibug

Tags: adobe-analytics

When I check Omniture for a custom link event I see the link type twice

[image]

We've had some issues related to custom link tracking so I want to confirm that this isn't a sign of an implementation issue. Fiddler is only showing it once, so could this be a known issue with Omnibug?

Comment: I've never seen this in Omnibug before. If you see it only shows one in the actual request (e.g. in the Net tab or in Fiddler) then it's okay and I would say this is indeed an Omnibug bug

Comment: If you're seeing that - can you pop over to https://github.com/simpsora/omnibug/issues and submit a new issue with the URL(s) that you're seeing that on? I'd like to take a look at it because I've never seen that either